# Is the PrimeFaces socket supposed to append every connection to the URL?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, push, primepush

I'm running the latest PrimeFaces showcase demo on GlassFish 4 and I'm running into the problem where every time the `socket.connect("/user")` is called, "/user" is simply being appended to the exiting URL.

```
requestContext.execute("PF('subscriber').connect('/" + username + "')");
```

Maybe the disconnect method is not working correctly?

The outcome is there are an increasing number of path segments so they don't get properly mapped to the path variables on the endpoint class.

A page refresh before making the connection works.

I know this came up in one similar post but I'm not allowed to comment.

[Primefaces Push - What are the methods in <p:socket/> client widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21253484/primefaces-push-what-are-the-methods-in-psocket-client-widget/21279586#21279586)

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Adding `this.cfg.request.url = this.cfg.url;` to the disconnect function in push.js seems to fix the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was a defect that has been fixed now.

https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/1132